How do I add an album cover using getID3 in wordpress?
Am trying to change the album cover of an mp3 file during upload in wordpress. I facing the same error message "Unexpected response from the server. The file may have been uploaded successfully. Check in the Media Library or reload the page.".
    <?php
require_once 'getID3-master/getid3/getid3.php';

function update_mp3_metadata($upload)
{
    $file_path = $upload['file'];

    // Check if getID3 is loaded correctly
    if ( !class_exists('getID3') ) {
        echo 'getID3 library not found.';
        return $upload;
    }

    $getID3 = new getID3;
    $tagWriter = new getid3_writetags;

    // Check if the uploaded file is an MP3
    if ( mime_content_type($file_path) === 'audio/mpeg' ) {

        $coverImagePath = get_template_directory() . '/public/images/yt.jpg';

        // Check if the cover image path is correct and file exists
        if ( !file_exists($coverImagePath) ) {
            echo "Cover image not found at: $coverImagePath";
            return $upload;
        }

        $tagData['attached_picture'][0] = [
            'data' => file_get_contents($coverImagePath),
            'picturetypeid' => 3,
            'description' => 'Cover',
            'mime' => 'image/jpeg',
        ];

        $tagWriter->filename = $file_path;
        $tagWriter->tagformats = ['id3v2.3'];
        $tagWriter->overwrite_tags = true;
        $tagWriter->tag_encoding = 'UTF-8';
        $tagWriter->tag_data = $tagData;

        if ( $tagWriter->WriteTags() ) {
            echo 'Tags written successfully.';
        } else {
            echo "Couldn't write tags: " . implode(', ', $tagWriter->errors);
        }
    }

    return $upload;
}

add_filter('wp_handle_upload', 'update_mp3_metadata');
?>

I started with the getId3 library included in Wordpress in the "includes/ID3" directory, there's no write.php file there. I thought that was the problem. Am using the downloaded library but still facing the same problem.

Do you have debug logging and error reporting turned on, and have you checked the logs?

The "unexpected response" is likely due to the fact that you are making outputs using echo all over the place there.
